# Adding text in a richtextbox after adding a graphic

Tags: winforms, richtextbox

When adding a graphic to the end of some text in a richtextbox.  It works great.  However, when I begin to add more text, the graphic is overwritten.  This is not the desired outcome.

I am using the clipboard method for taking a graphic from resources and pasting it into the richtextbox.

```
        // initiate the horizontal bar file
        Image image = Properties.Resources.hoz_line_212x4;

        // Put the image on the clipboard
        Clipboard.SetImage(image);

        //// Paste it into the rich text box.
        this.msgsrtbx.Paste();

        this.msgsrtbx.SelectionLength = 0;
        this.msgsrtbx.ScrollToCaret();
```

When I come to the next bit of text I want to place in teh richtextbox, the graphic is overwritten.  I would like it to still remain in the box.

Comment: Could you show the code you use when adding more text please?